# How to enable dropdown buttons one by one in angularjs(Cascading dropdown)

Tags: angularjs, cascadingdropdown

In cascading dropdowns ( eg:3 dropdowns), how to disable 2nd and 3rd dropdown initially and when user selects an option in 1st dropdown , 2nd dropdown should be enabled. And when the user selects an option in 2nd then 3rd dropdown should be enabled.

If anyone knows , please suggest me a way,how to do the above.

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  ng-click="openDropdown($event)">{{labelX}}
  <span ng-click="openDropdownFromA($event)"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu " >
    <li ng-repeat="data in A"   ng-click="Data($event,data)" >
        <a>{{data}}</a>     
    </li>
  </ul>



  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  ng-click="openDropdown($event)">{{labelY}}
  <span ng-click="openDropdownFromA($event)"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu " >
    <li ng-repeat="data in B"   ng-click="Data($event,data)" >
        <a>{{data}}</a>     
    </li>
  </ul>



  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button"  ng-click="openDropdown($event)">{{labelZ}}
  <span ng-click="openDropdownFromA($event)"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu " >
    <li ng-repeat="data in C"   ng-click="Data($event,data)" >
        <a>{{data}}</a>     
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: This is a very low effort question. You've shown no efforts to find a solution on your own (Note that you may have tried something, but we like to see the things that don't work!). Speaking of, there's a simple answer hidden here: each input comes linearly after the previous, just like counting could be described as each integer coming after the previous in the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you could use

```
ng-disabled="DropdownBDisabled"
```

on the dropdown that you want to enable\disable and then setup your on click method to change the value of the DropdownBDisabled variable accordingly.

Something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34296853/angularjs-disabling-drop-down)